# " AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' " issue came while coding for sentimental analysis

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

**CODE**

```py
def split_by_dot(x):
    return(x.split("."))

df2["snippet_split_by_dot"] = df2["snippet"].apply(split_by_dot) 
    
df2["snippet_split_by_dot"]
```

**Error**

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8776/397076871.py in split_by_dot(x)
      1 def split_by_dot(x):
----> 2     return(x.split("."))
      3 
      4 df2["snippet_split_by_dot"] = df2["snippet"].apply(split_by_dot)
      5 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: That would be because `split` only works with string and you are trying to split a float by the looks of it. You can try casting the variable to string before executing the split operation like `return str(x).split(".")`

Comment: you could use `print(x)` to see what value makes problem.

Comment: Please search for "[python] AttributeError" and what it means. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].